# NSIS: Detecting Tomcat Installation

Tags: apache, tomcat, nsis

I have been trying to detect if Tomcat is installed on a host system in my NSIS script.Here is the section that does it

```
Section Tomcat
ClearErrors 

Var /GLOBAL tomcatVersion
ReadRegStr $tomcatVersion HKLM "SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\7.0\Tomcat7" "InstallPath"
;ExecWait "$EXEDIR\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.exe"
DetailPrint "$tomcatVersion"
SectionEnd
```

When I go to "regedit" and check the path of that specific key, it has a value, but the print statement returns a blank.

Can someone suggest what is the best way to troubleshoot this and/or any errors that I might be facing?

There is an interesting thing I noticed, that If in the above code, if I point the ReadRegStr command to read

```
HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion"
```

It returns a value, so syntactically, the code does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the Tomcat installer is a 64 bit installer then a 32 bit process will not find that key, in NSIS you can use `SetRegView 64`.
- If you are using `RequestExectionLevel` in your script and the Tomcat installer was virtualized by UAC then you must read it from the [VirtualStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Unlikely in your case since you can see the key in regedit)
- [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is also handy to debug registry issues...

Comment: Thanks, that worked.. Adding the line "SetRegView 64" just before reading the registry provided the value.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but this thread comes up if you google for "nsis install tomcat", so I thought I would share this nice example I found...

https://github.com/mathiaslin/openmrs-pgh-190/blob/master/metadata/installer/installer_setup.nsh